# RuleUnit + Quarkus example's drl file - What is the difference between the usage of the variables `$l` and `$a`?

Tags: java, drools, kogito

I do not understand a few parts of this `drl` code, but I'll just post one question here:

https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/stable/ruleunit-quarkus-example/src/main/resources/org/kie/kogito/queries/RuleUnitQuery.drl

The full drl code is here:

```
package org.kie.kogito.queries;
unit LoanUnit;
import org.kie.kogito.queries.LoanApplication;
import org.kie.kogito.queries.AllAmounts;
rule SmallDepositApprove when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit < 1000, amount <= 2000 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(true) };
end
rule SmallDepositReject when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit < 1000, amount > 2000 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
rule LargeDepositApprove when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit >= 1000, amount <= maxAmount ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(true) };
end
rule LargeDepositReject when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit >= 1000, amount > maxAmount ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
rule NotAdultApplication when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age < 20 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
query FindApproved
    $l: /loanApplications[ approved ]
end
query FindNotApprovedIdAndAmount
    /loanApplications[ !approved, $id: id, $amount : amount ]
end
rule AllAmounts
when
    accumulate ( $a : /loanApplications ; $sum : sum($a.amount))
then
    allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));
end
query FindAllApplicationAmounts
    $a : /allAmounts
end
```

What is the difference between the usage of the variables `$l` and `$a`, given that they are both linked to `/loanApplications` in some way?  Are they considered local or instance variables?

I've extracted a couple of rules illustrating what I'm asking about here.  What actually goes into `$l` and `$a`, given that they're supposed to be different?

```
rule NotAdultApplication when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age < 20 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
rule AllAmounts
when
    accumulate ( $a : /loanApplications ; $sum : sum($a.amount))
then
    allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));
end
```

Comment: Please include the rules in question in your post itself. Except for globals, which are declared at the top of the file using the `global` keyword, all variables in drools are scoped to the rule, though some can be scoped even more discretely to a function (eg accumulate.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks, i've included 2 rules as examples.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Drools are similar to variables in Java.

For your first rule, `NotAdultApplication`, the result of `/loanApplications` is assigned to the variable `$l`. Its scope is the rule -- both the conditional (when) and consequence (then) clauses.

For your second rule, `AllAmounts`, there are two different variables: `$a` and `$sum`. Similar to `$l` in the first rule, `$sum` is scoped to the rule, and you can see that it's being used in the consequence. However `$a` is scoped to the [`accumulate` function](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-WHEN-elements-ref_drl-rules), not to the rule -- you can't access `$a` from the when clause.

The reason that these two variables are scoped differently is because they serve two different functions; their scope is really due to what they represent as part of the accumulation. If might be easier to understand if I rewrote the rule to look like this:

```
rule "AllAmounts (alternative version)"
when
  $applications: /loanApplications
  accumulate( $a: LoanApplication() from $applications,
              $sum: sum($a.amount))
then
  allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));
end
```

Hopefully this version is more clear: `$a` is a temporary internal variable that is used to help iterate through the loan applications; it's like the variable in foreach loop -- it gives us a reference to the individual load application. `$sum` is assigned to the output of the function, which is why you can use it on in the rule consequences.

If you think about it, it wouldn't make *sense* to try and access `$a` from outside of the accumulation -- what would it refer to?

This is broadly equivalent to this Java code:

```java
Collection<LoanApplication> $applications = getLoanApplications(); // or whatever the equivalent is for /loanApplications
  
double $sum = 0.0;
for ( LoanApplication $a : $applications ) {
  $sum += $a.amount;
}
// you can't access $a here -- what would it even mean?
```